# Manipulate the header of a ZIP file in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, zip

I am very old hand at VB6 (and still use it to this day) but am considering moving to VB.NET.   I cannot find the info on the MSDN (or here) so I figured I would ask.

Is there a way to read the header of a ZIP file (the comment) in VB.NET into a string variable?

Any help is certainly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this help? https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/1185508/How-do-I-find-header-file-in-VB-NET#answer1 Not a VB.NET person but it's what I found w some googling

Comment: It doesn't appear to be possible using the .NET Framework Zip support, but there may be support for it in a third-party compression library.  If you know the format well enough, you could probably write the raw file I/O to do it yourself.